# How can I generate a random sparse matrix with a specific probability of symmetric entries?

Tags: matrix, probability, gurobi

I'm working on a program that sorts individuals into teams based on a sparse matrix with binary entries, each entry corresponding to whether or not *i* is willing to work with *j* and so on. I have the program running, but I need to be able to test it on random matrices to observe some relationships between the results and the parameters.

What I'd like to find is some way to generate a matrix that has a a certain number of non-zero entries per row and a certain probability of symmetrical entries. That is, I want to be able to assign a specific number for P(w_ji = 1 | w_ij = 1) and use that to generate a matrix. I don't want symmetric matrices, but modeling this with completely random matrices would be inaccurate, since a real-world willingness matrix tends to be at least somewhat symmetric.

Does anyone know of anything I could use to generate such a matrix? I generally use python (with gurobi) and am open to installing any number of other libraries to help if I have to. If anyone else here uses gurobi, I would appreciate input on whether or not I could model matrix generation like this as an optimization problem using something like this for an objective function:

```
min <= sum(w[i,j] * w[j,i] for i in... for j in...) <= max
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a coefficient matrix with random distribution of 0 and 1 values, the easiest option is to pick a probability and do Bernoulli trials as to whether the value is 1. (If it is zero, omit the element for sparseness).

Alternately, if you need a random permutation of a fixed number of 0's and 1's, then try something like:

```
import random

n = 50
k = 10

positions = sorted(random.sample(range(n), k))
```

The list `positions` represents the nonzero elements you need.

With a matrix representation, this would be a good candidate for the [Gurobi matrix variable object, MVar](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_mvar.html).